# Why can't I define Symbol as a constructor?

Tags: javascript, constructor, paperjs

This is a snippet of my Javascript (paperjs) code:

```
var symbol = new Symbol(path);
```

it gives a warning - **"Do not use Symbol as a constructor"**

Is there anything else I could do here, to get rid of that warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the **[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)**

> The following syntax with the new operator will throw a TypeError:
>
> `var sym = new Symbol(); // TypeError`
>
> This prevents authors from
>   creating an explicit Symbol wrapper object instead of a new symbol
>   value and might be surprising as creating explicit wrapper objects
>   around primitive data types is generally possible (for example, new
>   Boolean, new String and new Number).

Just use `Symbol` as a function

```js
var symbol = Symbol(4);

console.log(typeof symbol); // outputs 'symbol'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Suren, it works :) Never thought about the official Documentation...

Comment: @Suren the question is, why is it not allowed? I saw the documentation but it does not tell me why.

Comment: @SoftwareGuy The statement `var sym = new Symbol()` throws an error in JavaScript because Symbol is a primitive data type in JavaScript and it cannot be instantiated using the new keyword.

Comment: thanks @SurenSrapyan - what I want to understand is why is it not allowed or what implications would it have if it were allowed? For example, in JavaScript, `String()` is allowed both with and without 'new' and it returns either a primitive (when used without 'new') or a wrapper object when used with 'new String()'. If we can do that with Strings, why not with Symbols?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/Symbol in the section new Symbol() - The article says that it is forbidden to create a wrapper object by default as it is done with new String or similar.

Instead you mad do next:

const sym = Symbol("foo");
const symObj = Object(sym);
typeof sym; // "symbol"
typeof symObj; // "object"

So, you still can make wrapper object - but why id hide? i do not know